# VSCode Terminal output - is not processed

Tags: python, json, linux, visual-studio-code

**update:** tried to solve this

on a fresh start in a newly installed VSCode on EndeavourOS i installed too

python and code-runner and wanted to do set the output of code to the terminal: according this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o4gDQvVkLU&list=PLIHcvkHKg_aNb0KS813WkPGhWtkNmnHJX&index=2

After installing python, open the command prompt/terminal, and type in python --version or py --version. If you have installed python successfully, you will see the version of python you have.

To have code runner output to the terminal instead of the built-in output console, click the settings icon (gear icon) on the bottom left corner. Scroll down until you see Code Actions on Save. Click settings.json and the file will open.

Add this line inside the json file: "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,

see how i added the line

[image]

but unfortunatly the output was not derived to the terminal

[image]

what goes wrong

**update:**  did tis but i do not know if it is correct

[image]

and get this:

[image]

what  do you say

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code directly to `settings.json`:

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

This line doesn't need to be in `editor.codeActionsOnSave`.

[image]

Comment: hello and good day - many many for the hint - i did to apply it but i am not sure if i got you right - see the update...in the posing above

Comment: Vscode also uses red wavy lines to remind you that there is an error in this file. Deleting lines 1-6 can solve the problem.